# How can I make a Portfolio Gallery with Filtering on my website without breaking the rest of my code? / Why won't my body content show up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to code a Portfolio Gallery with Filtering on my website using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have looked at multiple tutorials ([w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp), [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-filter-with-portfolio-gallery-using-html-css-and-javascript/)) and followed them exactly, but neither worked out. With w3Schools, I was left with a completely empty body content area, and with Geeks for Geeks, I had images in my body content area, but my sidebar and navigation bar were both totally trashed even though the changes in the code didn't relate to them.

So, here's what I'm trying to do: I have a webpage that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml11q.png), and I want to filter out the blocks by their color when I click on the buttons in the navigation bar. So if I were to click yellow, the result would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1c0B.png). (The actual grid of images is 3x3, and there are two yellow blocks in it.) I want them to sort properly into three columns as much as possible.

EDIT: Here is my original bugged code, solutions are in the comments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Mozart Armstrong Portfolio Graphic Design</title>
         <style>

            @font-face {
              font-family: Klik;
              src: url(klik-light-webfont.woff);
            }

            @font-face {
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              src: url(theboldfont.ttf);
            }

            .main {
              margin-left: 200px;
              padding: 105px 10px;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #000000;
              display: block;
              column-count: 3;
              column-width: 32%
              column-gap: 1%;
            }

            .main p {
              font-size: 24px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #000000;
            }
            
            .sidebar {
              height: 100%;
              width: 200px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 3;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              background-color: #000000;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .sidebar a {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .sidebar a:hover {
              color: #808080;
            }

            .sidebar b {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              font-size: 28px;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .sidebar c {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 13px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .navbar {
              position: absolute;
              padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
              height: 100px;
              width: 100%;
              right: 0;
              top: 0;
              z-index: 2;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              background-color: #808080;
            }

            .navbar a {
              padding: 20px 8px 16px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
            }

            .navbar b {
              padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
              width: 225px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .navbar c {
              padding: 25px 225px 0px 245px;
              width: 100%;
              height: 30px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 26px;
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              color: #000000;
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .navbar button {
              background-color: #000000;
              border: none;
              color: #ffffff;
              padding: 10px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
            }

            .navbar button:hover {
              background-color: #ffffff;
              border: none;
              color: #000000;
              padding: 10px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
            }

            
         </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="sidebar">
         <b>Mozart</b>
         <b>Armstrong</b>
         <c>design • marketing • branding</c>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
         <a href="#">Illustration</a>
         <a href="#">Animations</a>
         <a href="#">Photography</a>
         <a href="#">Writing</a>
         <a href="#">Fashion Design</a>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar">
         <c>Graphic Design</c>
         <b></b>
         <button onclick="">All</button>
         <button onclick="">Red</button>
         <button onclick="">Yellow</button>
         <button onclick="">Green</button>
         <button onclick="">Blue</button>
         <button onclick="">Pink</button>
       </div>
      <div class="main">
        <p></p><img src="Block2.png" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block.png" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block3.png" width=100%></img><nextcol>
        <p></p><img src="Block4.png" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block.png" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block2.png" width=100%></img><nextcol>
        <p></p><img src="Block5.png" width=100%><p></p><img src="Block3.png" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block.png" width=100%></img></img>
      </div>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your edited code using jQuery functions but you forget to import the jQuery library js file

Comment: @AdamP. I have imported jQuery and Isotope but the buttons are still not working. I've tried multiple browsers and I have tried downloading the files so that they can be locally imported.

Comment: I didn't see you were wanting to solve this with jQuery so I came up with a solution with vanilla JavaScript. Let me know if this is working for you. I had to give the `img` a data-index to make it work. Background colors are just because there weren't any images: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/LYxZQOd

Comment: @marmstrong fantastic! I will put it in an answer below feel from to mark answered or upvote

Comment: @BertW So the buttons are working and the content is in the right space, but for the "Green" and "Blue" sections, the second image that displays is skewed upwards (mostly off the page). I've poked around trying to fix this, but the only difference I found was the use of " in two instances whereas all other instances used just ', which I corrected for uniformity, and that had no impact. Everything else seems to be exactly the same between them all so I can't figure why just those two colors have this issue. https://i.imgur.com/MMWxNNn.png

Comment: I see what you are saying. I need some time to work out a solution, will get back when I can figure something out, thanks.

Comment: @marmstrong I believe I have figured out the problem. I used the original code you posted with the dummy images, I had to change where the `data-index` were because I needed to hide the `div` as well. I also changed the layout for `main` and used `flexbox`. Let me know if it works for you or if it needs further debugging: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/LYxZQOd

Comment: @BertW You overwrite the official Isotope animated filter... Congratulation... oh wait! no!

Comment: @AdamP. hmm, was confused because marmstrong deleted his original code example and I thought your answer html was the original example. Your solution looks a lot better with the animation for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with JavaScript:

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar button');
const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');

button.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', displayCard));

function displayCard(e) {
  for (let i =0; i < button.length; i++){
    if (e.target === button[i]) {
    if (button[i].textContent === 'All') {
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){  
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
      }
    } else if (button[i].textContent === 'Red'){
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].getAttribute('data-index') ==='2'){
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          img[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    } else if (button[i].textContent === 'Yellow'){
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].getAttribute('data-index') ==='3'){
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          img[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      } 
  } else if (button[i].textContent === 'Green'){
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].getAttribute('data-index') ==='4'){
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          img[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
} else if (button[i].textContent === 'Blue'){
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].getAttribute('data-index') ==='5'){
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          img[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
} else if (button[i].textContent === 'Pink'){
      for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        if (img[i].getAttribute('data-index') ==='1'){
          img[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          img[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img{
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
img[src="Block2.png"]{
  background-color: red;
}
img[src="Block3.png"]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
img[src="Block4.png"]{
  background-color: green;
}
img[src="Block5.png"]{
  background-color: blue;
}
img[src="Block.png"]{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Mozart Armstrong Portfolio Graphic Design</title>
         <style>

            @font-face {
              font-family: Klik;
              src: url(klik-light-webfont.woff);
            }

            @font-face {
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              src: url(theboldfont.ttf);
            }

            .main {
              margin-left: 200px;
              padding: 105px 10px;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #000000;
              display: block;
              column-count: 3;
              column-width: 32%
              column-gap: 1%;
            }

            .main p {
              font-size: 24px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #000000;
            }
            
            .sidebar {
              height: 100%;
              width: 200px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 3;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              background-color: #000000;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .sidebar a {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: CaviarDreams;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .sidebar a:hover {
              color: #808080;
            }

            .sidebar b {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              font-size: 28px;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .sidebar c {
              padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 13px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: block;
            }

            .navbar {
              position: absolute;
              padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
              height: 100px;
              width: 100%;
              right: 0;
              top: 0;
              z-index: 2;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              background-color: #808080;
            }

            .navbar a {
              padding: 20px 8px 16px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
            }

            .navbar b {
              padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
              width: 225px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
              color: #ffffff;
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .navbar c {
              padding: 25px 225px 0px 245px;
              width: 100%;
              height: 30px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 26px;
              font-family: theBoldFont;
              color: #000000;
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .navbar button {
              background-color: #000000;
              border: none;
              color: #ffffff;
              padding: 10px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
            }

            .navbar button:hover {
              background-color: #ffffff;
              border: none;
              color: #000000;
              padding: 10px 32px;
              text-align: center;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: inline-block;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: Klik;
            }

            
         </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="sidebar">
         <b>Mozart</b>
         <b>Armstrong</b>
         <c>design • marketing • branding</c>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
         <a href="#">Illustration</a>
         <a href="#">Animations</a>
         <a href="#">Photography</a>
         <a href="#">Writing</a>
         <a href="#">Fashion Design</a>
         <b></b>
         <b></b>
         <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar">
         <c>Graphic Design</c>
         <b></b>
         <button>All</button>
         <button>Red</button>
         <button>Yellow</button>
         <button>Green</button>
         <button>Blue</button>
         <button>Pink</button>
       </div>
      <div class="main">
        <p></p><img src="Block2.png" data-index='2' width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block.png" data-index="1" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block3.png" data-index='3' width=100%></img><nextcol>
        <p></p><img src="Block4.png" data-index="4" width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block.png" data-index='1' width=100%></img><p></p><img src="Block2.png" data-index='2' width=100%></img><nextcol>
        <p></p><img src="Block5.png" data-index='5' width=100%><p></p><img src="Block3.png" data-index='3' width=100%></img><p></p><img data-index='1' src="Block.png" width=100%></img></img>
      </div>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done, for example, with the [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) jQuery library:

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js


        // init Isotope
        var $grid = $('.main').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.img-block',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });

        // bind filter button click
        $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
          var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
          $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
        });

        // change is-checked class on buttons
        $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
          var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
          $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
          });
        });
```

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: Klik;
      src: url(klik-light-webfont.woff);
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: theBoldFont;
      src: url(theboldfont.ttf);
    }
    body{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .main {
      margin-left: 200px;
      padding: 105px 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: CaviarDreams;
      color: #000000;
      display: block;
      column-count: 3;
      column-width: 32%
      column-gap: 1%;
    }

    .main p {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-family: CaviarDreams;
      color: #000000;
    }

    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 200px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 3;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #000000;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .sidebar a {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: CaviarDreams;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
    }

    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #808080;
    }

    .sidebar b {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: theBoldFont;
      font-size: 28px;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
    }

    .sidebar c {
      padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-family: Klik;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
    }

    .navbar {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #808080;
    }

    .navbar a {
      padding: 20px 8px 16px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Klik;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .navbar b {
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
      width: 225px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Klik;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar c {
      padding: 25px 225px 0px 245px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-family: theBoldFont;
      color: #000000;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar button {
      background-color: #000000;
      border: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Klik;
    }

    .navbar button:hover {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: none;
      color: #000000;
      padding: 10px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Klik;
    }
    .img-block{
      margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mozart Armstrong Portfolio Graphic Design</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
   <b>Mozart</b>
   <b>Armstrong</b>
   <c>design • marketing • branding</c>
   <b></b>
   <b></b>
   <b></b>
   <a href="#">Graphic Design</a>
   <a href="#">Illustration</a>
   <a href="#">Animations</a>
   <a href="#">Photography</a>
   <a href="#">Writing</a>
   <a href="#">Fashion Design</a>
   <b></b>
   <b></b>
   <a href="#">About</a>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar">
   <c>Graphic Design</c>
   <b></b>
   <div id="filters" class="button-group">
     <button data-filter="*">All</button>
     <button data-filter=".img-red">Red</button>
     <button data-filter=".img-yellow">Yellow</button>
     <button data-filter=".img-green">Green</button>
     <button data-filter=".img-blue">Blue</button>
     <button data-filter=".img-pink">Pink</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="img-block img-red" >
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ff0000/fff" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-yellow">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ffff00/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-green">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/25b825/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-blue">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/2a31eb/ffffff" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-pink">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/db2aeb/ffffff" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-green">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/25b825/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-green">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/25b825/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-red">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ff0000/fff" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-red">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ff0000/fff" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-yellow">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ffff00/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

  <div class="img-block img-yellow">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/ffff00/000000" width="100%" />
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've copied your exact code response, and the image blocks finally appear in the right space without messing up the rest of the page. However, the buttons still aren't working. They're clickable but nothing changes.

Comment: Buttons are working both in this demo view and this [Codepen project](https://codepen.io/adampweb/pen/abpZqGV)